# Purpose of this IRepository class signature

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I am attempting to follow the repository pattern described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24591599/91811).

Can someone please shed some light on what this really means, and what the benefits of it are? The

> <TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity

part of the classes signature

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    TEntity Get(int id);

    int Save(TEntity entity);

    void Delete(TEntity entity);        
}
```

I do not see any noticeable effect in my implementation of IRepository:

```
public class AppUserRepository : Repository, IRepository<AppUser>
{
    public void Delete(AppUser entity)
    {
        using ( var context = new SourceEntities())
        {
            context.AppUsers.Attach(entity);
            context.AppUsers.Remove(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public AppUser Get(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new SourceEntities())
        {
            return context.AppUsers.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public int Save(AppUser entity)
    {
        using (var context = new SourceEntities())
        {
            if ( entity.Id == 0 )
            {
                // this is a new record
                context.AppUsers.Add(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                // existing record
                context.AppUsers.Attach(entity);
                context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            // save the record
            context.SaveChanges();

            return entity.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What effect did you expect to see?

Comment: Well, if I were to remove the <TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity part of the interface signature what would happen? Better yet, what is the benefit of having that as part of the signature?

Comment: Do you know what generic type constraints are (or rather why you would use them)?

Comment: Obviously not well enough to understand this. Please enlighten me. :-)

Comment: Frankly, if I were to remove that part of the interface's signature, I don't think the code I have written in the implementation would change at all. Hence, my questions on this...

Comment: I'll assume you know what generics are. Generics allow you to generalize the functionality of a class or method to apply to multiple different types, without you having to recreate the class for each difference in typing. But, what if you have a generic class or method that only works (well) with certain types? Without type constraints, you would not be able to limit this class or method to a subset of types; it would apply to every type in .NET, including your own. Using type constraints, you can say that only certain types make sense to use with a particular generic class or method.

Comment: Thank you Kenneth! I believe I get it now. Too bad I cannot mark this as the answer...If you post it as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: In general, as nozzleman points out, the constraint on the interface is not really necessary.  It's much more useful in a generic class, where it will enable you to call members of the constraining type on variables of the constrained type parameter.

Comment: My question was marked as a duplicate of "What does “T” mean in C#?". I don't think it is a duplicate. I wasn't asking what T means. I know what T means. I wanted to know what the benefits are of that IRepository class signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing right by questioning the purpose of that `IEntity` `interface`. Doing things just because other people do so it is cargo-cult, if you ask me.

Adding `interface`s, just for the purpose of abstraction, is adding superflous complexity. Ask yourself one question: Will you ever ***use*** `IEntity` in your code without caring about what type you are actually processing? If not, I suppose not to abstract that part. If you do, why not?

By looking at your code, it is perfectly clear what your `Repository` is doing. Don't change that just for the purpose of doing it.

For further reading, see this [blog post](http://programmingwithmosh.com/object-oriented-programming/why-i-dont-like-ientity-interfaces/).

### Update

IMO, if your repository needs the ability to "GetById", this could be a pro-argument for such an interface. On the other hand, why not implementing a `Find` method which accepts a expression to search an Entity?

Generally speaking, I prefer implementing abstract repositories for general purposes, and derived repositories for special needs of certain classes.

Comment: I tend to agree.  I generally put the type constraints on generic *classes,* but only if I need the constraint for the compiler.  I'll generally leave them off the interface.  In one of my projects, I spent hours *removing* overly-restrictive constraints when I realized that I could make the model more abstract than it had been.