# Is there a reason to separate `Model` and `Entity` classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa

In a recent interview with Amazon I have been rejected because I could not tell the advantage and disadvantage of making `model` and `Entity` classes different and same.

I have always created `Model` and `Entity` class same.

Can anybody help me on that with an example? Interviewer said you are making strong binding of `UI+DB` if you are keeping it same.

Comment: this might answer your question https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-model-object-and-a-entity-in-Spring-Boot

Answer (score 2):

It's true by making same class for Entity and Model you are tightly binding UI and DB, simple example of why should avoid is -> most of the time, we modify response like adding DTO, modifying format of date and so on. which could impact your database calls (DTO layer).[you can read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743995/what-is-difference-between-a-model-and-an-entity)