# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' to type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 4 layers

1. Controller Layer

   ```
    public class BaseMapController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Create an object for service layer interface and inject the object usinng constructor injection
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        public BaseMapController()
        {

        }
        private IBaseMapServiceInterface _basemapServiceInterface;

        public BaseMapController(IBaseMapServiceInterface thebasemapServiceInterface)
        {
            _basemapServiceInterface = thebasemapServiceInterface;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<MasterTblModel> GetSearch()
        {

          return _basemapServiceInterface.GetSearch();

        }
    }
   ```

   }
2. Service Layer

   ```
    public class BaseMapServiceInterfaceImpl : IBaseMapServiceInterface
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Create an object for data access layer interface and inject the object usinng constructor injection
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>

        private IBaseMapDataInterface _basemapDataInterface;

        public BaseMapServiceInterfaceImpl(IBaseMapDataInterface thebasemapDataInterface)
        {
            _basemapDataInterface = thebasemapDataInterface;
        }
        public IEnumerable<MasterTblModel> GetSearch()
        {
            return _basemapDataInterface.GetSearch();
        }
    }
   ```
3. DataAccessLayer

   ```
    public class BaseMapDataInterfaceImpl : IBaseMapDataInterface
    {

        public IEnumerable<MasterTblModel> GetSearch()
        {
            using (KGISApplication_Context Con = new KGISApplication_Context())
            {

                **return (IEnumerable<MasterTblModel>)Con.MASTER_TBL;**


            }
        }
    }
   ```
4. Model class

   ```
    public class MasterTblModel
    {
        public string MASTER_TBL_ID { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string Layer_Name { get; set; }
        public string table_alias { get; set; }
    }
   ```

solution is not have any compile time error, when I run it is showing 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[DataAccessLayer.MASTER_TBL]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[KGISModels.MasterTblModel]'.' from the data access layer

I did all the effort to type cast and change the linq query style, but could not able to fix. Any help will be helpful.
For DI I have used unity framework and registered the interface to implementation class properly.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a web app framework, not a data access library or ORM. The problem is that you're trying to use Entity Framework, an ORM, in an inappropriate way. A DbSet is neither a table nor a collection of objects. It's a *repository* for a specific entity, that's used to create LINQ queries. To retrieve data you need to execute those queries with `ToListAsync`, `ToArrayAsync` etc. In the rare case where you need to load an entire table into memory, you can use `ToListAsync` directly

Comment: An *entity* called `Master_TBL` is extremely unusual though. And using `con` for a DbContext suggests there's a misunderstanding on what EF is and how it works. A DbContext is neither a database connection nor a model of the database. It *uses* connections only when it has to load data or save changes. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work managing the *entities* used in a specific scenario. You can have multiple DbContexts in the same application, that make cover the same tables in different shapes, to cover different scenarios/use cases. Only small applications can get away with 1 DbContext

Comment: BTW you didn't post the relevant code. Since this has nothing to do with MVC, the controller and service class aren't involved. What matters is `KGISApplication_Context` and the class exposed by `MASTER_TBL`. Is it `MasterTblModel`, another unexpected name? Or is it a *different* class that you want mapped to `MasterTblModel`? `change the linq query style` you didn't post *any* query at all

Comment: If you want to map a different class to `MasterTblModel` you need to use `Select`. And use proper names - `MasterTblModel` sounds like a Doctor Who episode. The entity names should actually reflect their use. Let's say you have Sales or Inventory and orders. That's two scenarios where the Order or Customer **entities** will have different shapes. Let's assume sales, the DbContext should be eg `SalesContext` and the entities could be `Order` and `OrderDetails` exposed as `Orders` and `OrderDetails`. To map Orders to a ViewModel you need `context.Orders.Select(ord=>new OrderModel(....))`

Comment: The class and interface names, `BaseMapDataInterfaceImpl`, `IBaseMapDataInterface` and a `GetSearch` that returns everything is another strong indicator that something's wrong. EF is already abstract, it doesn't need an abstraction on top of it unless it's to *specialize* its use. Searching is the job of the database. Loading everything in memory and trying to search it without the help of a server's indexes, dozens of CPU cores and fast multi-SSD arrays is only going to slow things down

Comment: Relevant: [What is the difference between a model and an entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8744288/2791540)

Comment: Thank you sir, I changed the query like this using (KGISApplication_Context Con = new KGISApplication_Context())
            {
                var result = Con.MASTER_TBL.Select(x => new MasterTblModel()
                {
                    category = x.category,
                    Layer_Name=x.Layer_Name,
                   ....
                }).ToList();
                return result;       and it return the values.  Even I have installed the swagger and the api is working super fine.